# Linking to JQueryMobile files adds 3-4 second delay to UIWebView page load

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I've got a quite small simple web page that takes about 3 or 4 seconds to load in a UIWebView,the cause is the following files

```
<link rel="stylesheet"  href="jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.css" />  
<script src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.js"></script>
```

Take these out, and obviously it doesn't display properly, but it loads instantly.

Does anybody know of any workarounds or has experienced similar. 3-4 seconds it just too long.

Answer (score 0):

I wish I could be of help, but sadly I have the same issue.

The strange thing I found: this problem only applies when I load Jquery mobile in the first html file I'll be displaying after the app starts up. No clue why!